# Kendo Grid BeforeEdit event doesnt exist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid

The documentation clearly shows a BeforeEdit event on Grid:

- https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-beforeEdit
- https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridEventBuilder#methods-BeforeEdit(System.Func)

However there is no mention of what version this came into being for.  We are using version `2016.3.914`.  I get an error saying it doesn't exist (I tried using in MVC code and jquery).

```
function onDataBound(gridName) {
    return function (e) {
        var grid = $("#" + gridName).data("kendoGrid");
        species = extractSpecies(gridName);
        $("#Species").val(species);
        $("#" + gridName).data("kendoGrid").beforeEdit((e2) => {
            console.log("before edit");
        });
        console.log('WATCH01 NoiNLSConsignment / onDataBinding() - species is: ', species);
    }
}
```

---

```
OpenNlsApplication?exporterId=6190&applicationId=6191:2457 

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).beforeEdit is not a function(…)
    (anonymous function)    @ OpenNlsApplication?exporterId=6190&applicationId=6191:2457
    trigger                 @ kendo.all.min.js:25
    refresh                 @ kendo.all.min.js:51
    d                       @ jquery.min.js:2
    trigger                 @ kendo.all.min.js:25
    _process                @ kendo.all.min.js:28
    success                 @ kendo.all.min.js:27
    success                 @ kendo.all.min.js:27
    n.success               @ kendo.all.min.js:27
    i                       @ jquery.min.js:2
    fireWith                @ jquery.min.js:2
    y                       @ jquery.min.js:4
    c                       @ jquery.min.js:4
```

First question is how do you tell what version some functionality was added in Kendo?

Second is, I don't have control over the version used.  Is there a way I could reach into the life cycle to before the Edit occurs?  ie. `event.Edit()` is too late.

Comment: the 2017 edition of telerik accidently left this event out.  They fixed it in a later release.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer for the 2nd of my questions*.

I found out I only need the 'BeforeEdit' when `editing` (and not when `creating`) so it was easy enough to add some jquery to the edit button:

```
function onDataBound(gridName) {
    return function (e) {
        // This part is for when create a new Species / Animal Type
        species = extractSpecies(gridName);
        $("#Species").val(species);

        // This next part is for when edit
        // It would have been preferable to use the beforeEdit event, however that doesn't seem to exist in the version of
        // MVC Kendo that is being used currently (2016.3.914)
        $("div#" + gridName + " a[title*='edit this Animal']").on('click', function () {
            var localSpecies = extractSpecies(gridName);
            $("#Species").val(localSpecies);
            species = localSpecies; // Set the global
        });
    }
}
```

And in the definition of the Grid:

```
 <%  
   Html.Kendo().Grid<NoiNlsConsignmentVO>()
                    .Name(gridNameID)
                    ...
                    .Events(events => {
                        events.Edit("onEditLivestockClicked(\"" + gridNameID + "\")");
                        events.DataBound("onDataBound(\"" + gridNameID + "\")");
                        events.Save("onLivestockSave(\"" + gridNameID + "\")");
                    })
                    .Sortable()
                    .Render();
%>
```

* I'd add this as a comment given this is not a complete answer, however you can't add code (or newlines) to comments